# Content Security Policy: allowing all external images?

Tags: apache, security, xss, content-security-policy

I'd like to allow scripts only from my local server with certain exceptions like jQuery etc., but be flexible to load external images.
I'm aware that there is a directive like

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; img-src 'self' https://www.flickr.com;
```

to allow images from both, my own webserver and Flickr, but is it possible to allow images from *all* sources - or would this violate the whole concept of CSP and thus be impossible? I'm maintaining a blog often requiring to embed external images, so it basically comes up to a decision on whether it makes sense and is manageable to add CSP to my website or not.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Including images from all sources is a mostly safe practice in terms of security, but you may not like the content of the images that can be used.

To allow all images, use:

```
img-src * data:;
```

It's probably reasonable to limit this to `https:` sources so your users don't get a mixed content (broken lock) error:

```
img-src https: data:;
```

In either case, be sure to send `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"` to prevent content type sniffing that happens in Chrome/IE. I'm not sure if firefox will treat an image tag that points to a javascript file will treat that as Javascript due to sniffing, but your `script-src` should prevent that from being terrible. I'm not sure if `apis.google.com` hosts user scripts or if it's limited to typical open source libraries.

Comment: `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` is a useful tag, and I recommend it, however an `<image>` tag cannot load JavaScript from the server using the src attribute, even if the content-type does come back as `application/javascript`.

Comment: how to i allow also http ?

Comment: In the same way: `img-src http: https:;`. Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#hosts_values