# Content Security Policy as a blacklist

Tags: content-security-policy, blacklist

Can I use the Content Security Policy Header to **blacklist** the loading of scripts from certain domains?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can’t. When you create a CSP policy, it’s basically a “deny all” policy. You then add back “allow from” exceptions to that. But you can’t do it the other way around; this is, you can’t, in a CSP policy, express “allow all” as a default and then add back specific “deny from” exceptions.

Comment: I found it to be important to segregate my CSPs, more liberal for images, less so for scripts. Here is another response about that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776011/content-security-policy-allowing-all-external-images